# Замена текста в кнопке, Modx Revo

Tags: modx, revo

Не могу изменить текст в кнопке отправки формы, это для ajaxform, вот как записана в коде:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Отправить сообщение">[[%af_submit]]</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Запись в value не помогает(
Остается постоянно текст - Отправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `[[%af_submit]]` пишите ваш текст, который должен быть в кнопке

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
        value="Отправить сообщение">Отправить сообщение</button>
```